Is there a better way to model thin pipes around a larger cylinder?
I want to model this (edit: this is a podium/ stand for placing objects)


I'm new to Blender/ modelling and decided to manually make thinner pipes around a larger cylinder, like this:

I was just wondering if there is a better way to do this?
Edit: To add more info on what I'm doing - I'm making a thinner pipe and putting it outside a larger one (Image 3 - the highlighted circle represents the top view of one of the pipes).
Then, I copy the pipe and move them manually around the edge of the larger cylinder, making sure that half of it is sticking out. I'm trying to keep everything looking symmetrical as much as I can.
Edit 2: I was able to finish this manually and am quite happy with the results


Your way of doing it isn't bad. For a lot of cases, it would be sufficient. Do you want to do something else with this object after that ? It would guide our answers.

@Lutzi glad to hear that and thank you for your response! This is supposed to be a podium/ stand and I'll probably keep an object (a bottle perhaps) on top of it.

If it's only a secondary object in your render and you're new to Blender, I would suggest keeping your workflow. Keep in mind you won't be able to easily change the small cylinders.

In geonodes you could use a mesh circle and use every point to spawn a smaller cylinder

You should describe your way in addition to the screenshot. A single screenshot does not tell us much - imagine if someone posted a single image to describe a modelling workflow as an answer...

I think you should really edit the question and provide full information about what and how you do. I tried to write an answer with suggestions of how you could improve what you do just to realise I am just guessing what it is that you do...

@MartynasŽiemys I added some more details in the edit. If it's not sufficient, could you tell me what kind of information will be helpful?

This question is more suited for Blenderartists.org forums than BSE. It can not have one definite answer and is in my opinion too broad for here, because it requires general modelling tips on various techniques. I would recommend seeking for guidance on blenderatsists.org. You can duplicate and rotate around 3D cursor, then repeat last(R) or use an array modifier, or work with only a few edges to make it simpler and then extrude for example.

There a number of ways to accomplish the task of positioning tubes around a cylinder as in shown in your screen captures. The fastest and probably the easiest way in my experience would be to do the following:

Add the initial cylinder mesh
Go to the cylinder's edit mode and turn on x-ray view
Go to side vew of the cylinder and box select all of the vertical edges of the cylinder
Hit Ctrl + D to duplicate the selected edges and then right click the mouse to bring up the object menu
In the object menu scroll to the bottom and select seperate by selection.
Hit Tab key and select your new object of vertical edges
With the duplicated edges object selected, right click the mouse again to bring up the object menu and select convert to curve
In the Data tab go to the Geometry section go to Bevel and select Round
When you click the arrow of the Depth button you will see the edges turn into pipes.
Set the pipes to the appropriate diameter desired and check the Fill Caps box.

From there you can either right click on the newly created pipes object and convert them back to a mesh and then join them to the cylinder or leave them as curves.
